# gSOAP Error 400 HTTP Bad Request

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asmx, gsoap

I am getting an error when i make a call like :

```
soap_call___ns1__Sumar(soap,NULL,NULL,&oper,&resp)
```

> Error 400 fault al source [no subcode] "HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request"
>   Detail: [no detail]

ASMX Service was published on IIS, on local network at the same PC. I can consume the service from a c# client without problems but when i try to consume the service via gSOAP client it show the error.

Im using gSOAP 2.8.29, i think there was no problem building the files with wsdl2h and soapcpp2 tools. Here is my code.

Please, if someone know the cause of this error help me.
Thanks all.

**gSOAP Client**

```
#include "stdio.h"

#include "WCdataSoap.nsmap" 
#include "soapH.h" 

int main()
{
  struct soap *soap = soap_new(); 
  struct _ns1__SumarResponse sum;
  struct _ns1__Sumar oper;
  oper.a = 2;
  oper.b = 2;
  printf("a = %d\n", oper.a);
  printf("b = %d\n", oper.b);

  if (soap_call___ns1__Sumar(soap, NULL, NULL, &oper, &sum) == SOAP_OK)
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
  else
    soap_print_fault(soap, stderr);

  soap_destroy(soap); 
  soap_end(soap); 
  soap_free(soap); 

}
```

**soapClientC.c**

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
#pragma option push -w-8060
#pragma option push -w-8004
#endif
#include "soapH.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

SOAP_SOURCE_STAMP("@(#) soapClient.c ver 2.8.29 2016-04-20 02:44:39 GMT")


SOAP_FMAC5 int SOAP_FMAC6 soap_call___ns1__Sumar(struct soap *soap, const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, struct _ns1__Sumar *ns1__Sumar, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *ns1__SumarResponse)
{   struct __ns1__Sumar soap_tmp___ns1__Sumar;
    if (soap_endpoint == NULL)
        soap_endpoint = "http://localhost/MyService/WCdata.asmx";
    if (soap_action == NULL)
        soap_action = "http://localhost/MyService/Sumar";
    soap_tmp___ns1__Sumar.ns1__Sumar = ns1__Sumar;
    soap_begin(soap);
    soap->encodingStyle = NULL;
    soap_serializeheader(soap);
    soap_serialize___ns1__Sumar(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__Sumar);
    if (soap_begin_count(soap))
        return soap->error;
    if (soap->mode & SOAP_IO_LENGTH)
    {   if (soap_envelope_begin_out(soap)
         || soap_putheader(soap)
         || soap_body_begin_out(soap)
         || soap_put___ns1__Sumar(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__Sumar, "-ns1:Sumar", NULL)
         || soap_body_end_out(soap)
         || soap_envelope_end_out(soap))
             return soap->error;
    }
    if (soap_end_count(soap))
        return soap->error;
    if (soap_connect(soap, soap_endpoint, soap_action)
     || soap_envelope_begin_out(soap)
     || soap_putheader(soap)
     || soap_body_begin_out(soap)
     || soap_put___ns1__Sumar(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__Sumar, "-ns1:Sumar", NULL)
     || soap_body_end_out(soap)
     || soap_envelope_end_out(soap)
     || soap_end_send(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    if (!ns1__SumarResponse)
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    soap_default__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, ns1__SumarResponse);
    if (soap_begin_recv(soap)
     || soap_envelope_begin_in(soap)
     || soap_recv_header(soap)
     || soap_body_begin_in(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    soap_get__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, ns1__SumarResponse, "ns1:SumarResponse", NULL);
    if (soap->error)
        return soap_recv_fault(soap, 0);
    if (soap_body_end_in(soap)
     || soap_envelope_end_in(soap)
     || soap_end_recv(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    return soap_closesock(soap);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
#pragma option pop
#pragma option pop
#endif
```

**soapH.h**

```
#ifndef soapH_H
#define soapH_H
#include "soapStub.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifndef WITH_NOIDREF
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_markelement(struct soap*, const void*, int);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_putindependent(struct soap*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_getindependent(struct soap*);
#endif
SOAP_FMAC3 void *SOAP_FMAC4 soap_getelement(struct soap*, int*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_putelement(struct soap*, const void*, const char*, int, int);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_ignore_element(struct soap*);

SOAP_FMAC3 const char ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_faultcode(struct soap *soap);

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_byte_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_byte_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_byte(struct soap*, char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_byte(struct soap*, const char*, int, const char *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 char * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_byte(struct soap*, const char*, char *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_byte(struct soap*, const char *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_byte
#define soap_write_byte(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || soap_put_byte(soap, data, "byte", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 char * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_byte(struct soap*, char *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_byte
#define soap_read_byte(soap, data) ( soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_byte(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_int_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_int_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_int(struct soap*, int *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_int(struct soap*, const char*, int, const int *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_int(struct soap*, const char*, int *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_int(struct soap*, const int *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_int
#define soap_write_int(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || soap_put_int(soap, data, "int", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 int * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_int(struct soap*, int *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_int
#define soap_read_int(soap, data) ( soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_int(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Fault_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Fault_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Fault * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Fault
#define soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, data), 0) || soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, data, "SOAP-ENV:Fault", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Fault * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Fault(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Fault *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Fault
#define soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Fault(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Reason_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Reason_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Reason * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Reason
#define soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, data), 0) || soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, data, "SOAP-ENV:Reason", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Reason * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Reason
#define soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Detail_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Detail_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Detail * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Detail
#define soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, data), 0) || soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, data, "SOAP-ENV:Detail", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Detail * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Detail
#define soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Detail(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Code_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Code_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Code *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct SOAP_ENV__Code *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Code * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Code *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Code
#define soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, data), 0) || soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, data, "SOAP-ENV:Code", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Code * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Code
#define soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Code(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Header *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Header *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct SOAP_ENV__Header *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Header * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Header *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, const struct SOAP_ENV__Header *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Header
#define soap_write_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, data), 0) || soap_put_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, data, "SOAP-ENV:Header", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Header * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Header *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Header
#define soap_read_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_SOAP_ENV__Header(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE___ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE___ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct __ns1__Sumar *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const struct __ns1__Sumar *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct __ns1__Sumar *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct __ns1__Sumar * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char*, struct __ns1__Sumar *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const struct __ns1__Sumar *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write___ns1__Sumar
#define soap_write___ns1__Sumar(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize___ns1__Sumar(soap, data), 0) || soap_put___ns1__Sumar(soap, data, "-ns1:Sumar", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct __ns1__Sumar * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get___ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct __ns1__Sumar *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read___ns1__Sumar
#define soap_read___ns1__Sumar(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default___ns1__Sumar(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get___ns1__Sumar(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE__ns1__SumarResponse_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE__ns1__SumarResponse_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const struct _ns1__SumarResponse *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct _ns1__SumarResponse *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__SumarResponse * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const char*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const struct _ns1__SumarResponse *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write__ns1__SumarResponse
#define soap_write__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, data), 0) || soap_put__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, data, "ns1:SumarResponse", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__SumarResponse * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get__ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read__ns1__SumarResponse
#define soap_read__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get__ns1__SumarResponse(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE__ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE__ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct _ns1__Sumar *);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const struct _ns1__Sumar *);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char*, int, const struct _ns1__Sumar *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__Sumar * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char*, struct _ns1__Sumar *, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const struct _ns1__Sumar *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write__ns1__Sumar
#define soap_write__ns1__Sumar(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || (soap_serialize__ns1__Sumar(soap, data), 0) || soap_put__ns1__Sumar(soap, data, "ns1:Sumar", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__Sumar * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get__ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct _ns1__Sumar *, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read__ns1__Sumar
#define soap_read__ns1__Sumar(soap, data) ( ((data) ? (soap_default__ns1__Sumar(soap, (data)), 0) : 0) || soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get__ns1__Sumar(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const char *, int, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *const*, const char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Reason ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason *const*, const char*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Reason ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Reason(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Reason **, const char*, const char*);
#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const char *, int, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *const*, const char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Detail ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail *const*, const char*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Detail ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Detail(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Detail **, const char*, const char*);
#endif

#endif

#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const char *, int, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *const*, const char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Code ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, const char*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code *const*, const char*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct SOAP_ENV__Code ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Code(struct soap*, struct SOAP_ENV__Code **, const char*, const char*);
#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const char *, int, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *const*, const char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__SumarResponse ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, const char*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse *const*, const char*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__SumarResponse ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_PointerTo_ns1__SumarResponse(struct soap*, struct _ns1__SumarResponse **, const char*, const char*);
#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct _ns1__Sumar *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char *, int, struct _ns1__Sumar *const*, const char *);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__Sumar ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, const char*, struct _ns1__Sumar **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct _ns1__Sumar *const*, const char*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 struct _ns1__Sumar ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_PointerTo_ns1__Sumar(struct soap*, struct _ns1__Sumar **, const char*, const char*);
#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE__XML_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE__XML_DEFINED
#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE__QName_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE__QName_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default__QName(struct soap*, char **);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize__QName(struct soap*, char *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out__QName(struct soap*, const char*, int, char*const*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 char * * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in__QName(struct soap*, const char*, char **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put__QName(struct soap*, char *const*, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write__QName
#define soap_write__QName(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || soap_put__QName(soap, data, "QName", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 char ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get__QName(struct soap*, char **, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read__QName
#define soap_read__QName(soap, data) ( soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get__QName(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifndef SOAP_TYPE_string_DEFINED
#define SOAP_TYPE_string_DEFINED
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_default_string(struct soap*, char **);
SOAP_FMAC3 void SOAP_FMAC4 soap_serialize_string(struct soap*, char *const*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_string(struct soap*, const char*, int, char*const*, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 char * * SOAP_FMAC4 soap_in_string(struct soap*, const char*, char **, const char*);
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_put_string(struct soap*, char *const*, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_write_string
#define soap_write_string(soap, data) ( soap_free_temp(soap), soap_begin_send(soap) || soap_put_string(soap, data, "string", NULL) || soap_end_send(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

SOAP_FMAC3 char ** SOAP_FMAC4 soap_get_string(struct soap*, char **, const char*, const char*);

#ifndef soap_read_string
#define soap_read_string(soap, data) ( soap_begin_recv(soap) || !soap_get_string(soap, (data), NULL, NULL) || soap_end_recv(soap), (soap)->error )
#endif

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

And Finally my ASMX file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WCdata
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/MyService/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WCdata : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int Sumar(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it defined anywhere. Are you using text/xml or application/soap+xml?  I've found i need to use text/xml with WCF services.

Comment: It suppose that im using "application/soap+xml" on gSOAP v2.8.29, I was looking for some information about this error and i have found that it could be a "namespace error" or "soap action error" or maybe "soap version mismatch". Im new using gSOAP, this client was only a test project so i need to understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: I had an app that would work with text/xml, but would return a "400 Bad request" when it was sent application/soap+xml. Never found out why. Try text/xml.

Comment: How i can force gSOAP client to use text/xml request ??

Comment: Don't know offhand. You'll have to look that up in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve the problem. There was some things that i had to do and i explain it now.

Before start the post sorry if my english is not perfect.

First of all, you must take care of the compiler you are using. There is some problems with compilers and you should try to have only one installed in your SO and set in Global Path Variable.

Maybe you should have to turn off your firewall and stop to use some proxys if you are using one in order to discard this possible error.

Then please make sure that all the generate files process with gsoap tools (wsdl2h, soapcpp2) be ok.

If you done all the steps and you have the error:

> "stdsoap2.c undefined reference to wctomb_s"

you have to edit the stdsoap2.c file at line 12626 and 12839, comment the code

```
    //m = 0;
    //wctomb_s(&m, buf, sizeof(buf), (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
```

and add the line code

```
m = wctomb(buf, (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
```

result :

```
m = wctomb(buf, (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
//m = 0;
//wctomb_s(&m, buf, sizeof(buf), (wchar_t)(c & 0x7FFFFFFF));
```

Then you should'nt have more problems and the second part is in the case you get error 415.

If you have error 415, is a conflict error between comunicate client - server so you must be sure if the client side request and server side receive, client side receive and server side response are using the same SOAP protocol version (1.1, 1.2) so you maybe need to change your SOAP namespaces file "xxxxxx.nsmap".

```
SOAP_NMAC struct Namespace namespaces[] = {
        {"SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", NULL},
        {"SOAP-ENC", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding", NULL},
        {"xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema-instance", NULL},
        {"xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema", NULL},
        {"arr", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays", NULL, NULL},
        {"tempuri", "http://tempuri.org/", NULL, NULL},
        {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
    };
```

look this namespace equals to soap 1.1

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
```

the other one equals to soap 1.2

```
"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

to resolve the error 415, u should have to change de order of the namespaces or change the gsoap files compile mode using de -1 command to force use 1.1 version. Like this example:

```
soapcpp2 -CL -I(gsoap /Import path) -1 (file generated wsdl2h).h
```

Thats all, after all steps you should finally can consume your service method without problems.